# Would a question regarding making homemade pet (kitten/cat) food be considered off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

After recently acquiring a kitten and buying kitten food, I looked at the ingredients and was pretty grossed out at what it actually listed. Would I be able to ask a question pertaining to how to prepare the food or the like on SA or would this be considered off-topic?

I know if I asked a question pertaining to a recipe for cat food that it would be considered off topic, but then I wonder if I would even be able to ask a question about making food for kittens/cats.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This would be a great example for the [Pets site proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5489/pets). Far better, in fact, than most of their existing examples. Consider supporting that proposal if you haven't already.

Comment: @Aaronut: Great idea, I didn't know that a Pet site was being proposed. Thanks for the information.

Comment: Not to be confused with http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/31/horse-dog-pet-preparation-questions !

Comment: I don't think making pets food would be appealing to most people.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it would be off topic. Our site is for professional and amateur cooks. Making pet food doesn't fall into that category.

We will accept pictures of your kitten attached to this question though.

Comment: I figured it would be off topic but thought I should ask just in case.

Comment: His name is Felix.

Comment: @duchess He's adorable :)